# vim theme showing up strange in tmux

Tags: command-line, themes, vim, colors, tmux

My vim is configured like so:

```
  syntax on
  colorscheme brogrammer
  set nu
  set expandtab
  set tabstop=4
  set autoindent
```

My tmux is configured like so:

```
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"
```

When I run vim in tmux I get the background color in the first and last rows in vim and on the borders. The grey is the background color of my vim theme and the blue is the background color of my terminal.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably the colorscheme is incomplete, as your vim configuration seems fine. Have you tried other colorschemes like molokai, wombat etc? Do they work fine?

Comment: @VladTarniceru unfortunately the same thing happens with built in colorschemes

Comment: Have you tried another terminal? Does it work in the default terminal?

Comment: I've only tried it in the default Terminal, which other one should I try?

Comment: Try [molokai](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai)

Answer (score 1):

Check the $TERM currently in use before running tmux.
`echo $TERM`

if needed adjust it `TERM=xterm-256color` then restart tmux.

if it's working define the TERM in your terminal settings to make it persistent.
Look for "Terminal type string" in Connection > data in the settings of your terminal (putty, kitty...)

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me as stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427650/vim-in-tmux-background-color-changes-when-paging#15095377

you need to put

```
if &term =~ '256color'
    " disable Background Color Erase (BCE) so that color schemes
    " render properly when inside 256-color tmux and GNU screen.
    " see also http://snk.tuxfamily.org/log/vim-256color-bce.html
    set t_ut=
endif
```

in your .vimrc.